# How to take a scanner object and make it a String

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner, replaceall

I need help doing the following:

1. receiving input using Scanner class (I got this)
2. taking input from scanner and making it a String
3. use `replaceAll` to remove numbers 0-9 from user input.

The below code is what I have so far but it is only returning user input and not removing numbers:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner firstname = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
    String firstname1 = firstname.next();
    firstname1.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");
    System.out.println(firstname1);
```

Updated Code.  Thank you Hovercraft. I am now investigating how to retrieve all alpha characters as with the code below, I am only getting back the letters prior to the numeric values entered by the user:

```
import java.util.Scanner;    

public class Assignment2_A {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner firstname = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter your first name:");
        String firstname1 = firstname.next();
        firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("[^A-Z]","");
        System.out.println(firstname1);
```

Comment: You've a problem here: `firstname1.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");` as this doesn't change the firstname1 String but rather **returns** a changed String. You have to assign the String returned back to the firstname1 variable: `firstname1 = firstname1.replaceAll("[^0-9]","");` The reason for this is because *Strings are immutable*. You can't change a String object once it's been created, but you can change the String object that a String variable refers to, a subtle but important distinction.

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft Full of Eels.  I am getting very close thanks to you.  I have updated my code to the following and am now only getting numbers back.  How could I update this to only retrieve alpha characters (so not 0-9)?

Answer (score 4):

```
String input = yourScannerObject.nextLine ();
```

where "yourScannerObject" is the name you give your scanner.

Answer (score 1):

What method did you use to scan? is it `{scanner object name}.next()` ?

if so you have got a string and all that you have to do is create some string, and save the input to it, e.g.:

- `String str="";`
- `str = {scanner object name}.next();`

before using anything in java, I would advise you to read the API :

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()

Answer (score 0):

> receiving input using Scanner class (I got this)
>
> taking input from scanner and making it a String
>
> use replaceAll to remove numbers 0-9 from user input.

Here's an example:

```
String in;
Scanner scan = new Scanner("4r1e235153a6d 6321414t435hi4s 4524str43i5n5g");
System.out.println(in = (scan.nextLine().replaceAll("[0-9]", ""))); // use .next() for space or tab
```

Output:

```
read this string
```

The problem in your code is the regex "[^A-Z]" is set to remove all non-alphabet capital characters. This means you remove all lower case as well. You could say "[^a-zA-Z]", but then you're also removing special characters.